# Как вывести больше категорий продукта на странице edit-tags.php в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице edit-tags.php в вордпресс часть категорий на второй странице. Мне нужно что бы все категории были на одной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справа вверху-"настройки экрана" и ставь сколько надо выводить.